# Protecting Open XML Document using EPP Plus library

Tags: openxml-sdk

I am using [EPP Plus library](http://epplus.codeplex.com) to create my excel documents. I would like to protect my document/cells. I can lock my cells but I am unable to lock my document. Can anybody please assist me with how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I resolved it. It was pretty easy. Each cell has property locked in style. So basically we need to unlock cells which are need to be editable. then we lock the whole sheet. It does the trick :)